# Triple Monitor stopped working on OptiPlex 9010

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

On my Dell Optiplex 9010, I was running 3 monitors: 2 DP's to VGA and the onboard VGA. I recently got a new monitor with HDMI so I went with a DP to HDMI. Ever since then, I can only run 2 monitors. Even when I go back to all VGA, still only 2 monitors. As soon as I use Windows 10 settings to Extend Monitor, the other one shuts off, always the onboard VGA. Its very confusing as it was working fine before. I even used the Dell Driver Update on the video card.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.
Edit: Both DP adapters are Dell adapters.(Part #RN699)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all you've done but here's a bit of info.

I have had bios break these. Check your bios settings.

Put the old driver back in. Revert it to what it was to see if that helps.

Try setting the resolution lower in windows. Sometimes the native resolution of a monitor is to high for some adaptors especially when using multiple monitors or upgrading to newer ones. If it works with them all set to 600x800 work your way up until it fails.

Just fyi... display port has 4 separate digital video streams. HDMI has one. You can get Dp monitors with an in and out and daisy chain 4 of them on 1 DP. Only telling you this in case it helps troubleshoot.